# Pointer,a static member function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, static

I need help for explaining to me how is used here the word static, how it works and where  can use it?

```
class Constructor 
{
private:
static Constructor constructor;
public:
static Constructor* constructor();

};
Constructor Constructor::constructor;
Constructor* constructor::constructor()
{
    return &constructor;
}
```